# No errors when a Dataflow job is hitting Pub/Sub Subscriber throughput quota

Tags: gcloud

Is there a way to know that Dafaflow job reading from a Pub/Sub topic is hitting a quota `Cloud Pub/Sub API Subscriber throughput, kB per minute`.

There were no indications of problems in the log, however a pipeline was not able to keep up with backlog of messages from Pub/Sub topic.

**Update:** I meant to find out programmatically (e.g. via en exception/an error log).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Pub/Sub quota limits](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#quotas), there are Subscriber throughput quotas visible on the [APIs and services quotas dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/pubsub.googleapis.com/quotas?project=_&_ga=2.142548146.-1094141927.1572886814)(Cloud Console > API & Services > Dashboard > Cloud Pub/Sub API > Quota).

If you find that you have hit a limit you may be able to request an increase via the edit option (pencil icon) next to "limits".

Comment: If the aforementioned quota is being hit, please check if there is any explicit error messages in [Stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) and if there is not then monitoring the usage using [Stackdriver monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/) with [Pub/Sub metrics subscription 
 request count metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub) should allow you to monitor the usage of Subscriber throughput.

Comment: This [overview of quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota) doesn't seem to detail any options of programmatically viewing pub/sub quotas directly.